# Триггер для добавления данных в другую таблицу

Tags: oracle, plsql

Всем привет, пытаюсь написать триггер , который при изменении таблицы будет добавлять запись в связанную другую. Из многочисленных чтений получилось написать подобное:

```
trigger histop_in
after insert or update
on operation
FOR EACH ROW
begin 
insert into history_operat (id, id_tt_ch, date_ddmm, summ, id_user)
values (:new.id, :new.id_tt_ch, :new.date_ddmm, :new.summ, :new.id_user);
end histop_in;
```

Но по иронии, при попытке все это скомпилить, не выходит, ссылается на эту часть кода:

```
(:new.id, :new.id_tt_ch, :new.date_ddmm, :new.summ, :new.id_user);
```

Comment: Т е предлагаете ввести переменные и уже их передавать в инсерт ?

Comment: вот и подумай. пока я вижу только рисовки, по существу ни одного совета

Comment: Не понятны ваши комментарии, что вы ими хотели сказать? И каков ваш вопрос, почему при наличии синтактических ошибок не удаётся скомпилировать, или какой-то другой?